# Is there a relation between a smooth function and a separable function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
If $f$ is separable in its coordinates, i.e $f(x,y) = g(x)h(y)$, does it satisfy some smoothness property? For example, is it necessary continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$? With first derivative (if it exists) continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is not necessarily separable in its coordinates. Are there bounds known such that it can be approximately written with a sum of separable functions $g_i,h_i$ ?

Comment: Perhaps a trivial example: the function $f(x,y) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ is separable ($g(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}, h(y)=1$), but $g'$ is not defined at $x=0$, so cannot be continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Definitly NO to all the suggestions in the first paragraph.